# Bitbucket pipelines: echo environment variable

Tags: bash, environment-variables, bitbucket, slack-api, bitbucket-pipelines

I have a very simple pipeline for the tags. When I do the tag, I want to send simple slack webhook. My issue is that environment variable `$BITBUCKET_TAG` is not rendered neither in `echo` nor in slack message.

```
pipelines:
  tags:
    '*':
    - step:
        script:
        - echo $BITBUCKET_TAG 
        - curl -X POST "https://hooks.slack.com/services/mysecuritykey" -H "Content-Type:application/json" -H "cache-control:no-cache" -d '{"username":"CoreLib tag","text":"Tag *$BITBUCKET_TAG* has been created"}'
```

and I get this in Slack

```
CoreLib tag [12:50 PM]

Tag $BITBUCKET_TAG has been created
```

What I want to achieve is to render the `$BITBUCKET_TAG` value in my `echo` and in Slack message properly, smth like:

```
CoreLib tag [12:50 PM]

Tag v2019.1.1 has been created
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Basic solution is super simple.

Instead of `$BITBUCKET_TAG` should be `'"$BITBUCKET_TAG"'`.

```
echo -d '{"username":"CoreLib tag","text":"Tag *'"$BITBUCKET_TAG"'* has been created"}'
```

Taken from here:
https://superuser.com/questions/835587/how-to-include-environment-variable-in-bash-line-curl

Comment: Sorry, may you please check your answer? Are the single quotes outwards or the double quotes?

Comment: @Sammy thanks for pointing the error out in my answer. Corrected it, please check.

Comment: This doesn't address the issue with `echo`

Comment: @CodyBugstein can you try $echo '"$BITBUCKET_TAG"' ? I don't work on bitbucket project anymore thus can't validate. But the approach should be the same as in my original answer.